MOS differential amplifier output swing
Why is the maximum output voltage swing of a MOS differential amplifier 2Vdd-4Vdsat? I understand that the voltage swing of a MOS CS amplifier, but I don't know how they got that the voltage swing of a single ended differential amplifier is Vdd-2Vdsat according to the picture below.
